# How to upload multiple images Using django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms

I have Following Code in my models.py

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_images= models.ImageField(upload_to='image/')
```

My forms.py is

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = "__all__"
```

and in my Views.py file is having following code

```
def myfunction(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form = MyForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponse('Data Inserted')
        else:
            return HttpResponse('form is invalid')
```

this Code is inserting single image into Database and directory.i want to Add multiple images into my directory and database. here i am making API so i am sending formdata(image) from [`postman`](https://www.postman.com/) app.
how to Upload multiple images?

Answer (score 0):

`ImageField` can store only one image. If you need to upload multiple images, you should create separated ImageModel:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    pass

class ImageModel(models.Model):
    model_fk = models.ForeignKey(MyModel)
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='image/', related_name='images')
```

Send your images in a list, then read that list in your view and create `ImageModel` instance for each image.